# Что необходимо для того, чтобы iOS-приложение попало в App Store (App Store Submission)?

Tags: ipad, ios, objective-c, appstore, iphone

**Последнее обновление:**

Я опубликовал ответ на этот свой вопрос в виде статьи в моем блоге, так как этот топик был закрыт, как "не по теме": [Re: Что необходимо для того, чтобы iOS-приложение попало в App Store?](http://stanislaw.github.io/2016/04/04/how-to-app-store.html).

---

В связи с тем, что приблизилось время, когда я буду отправлять своё первое приложение на ревью в App Store, я хочу задать следующий очень актуальный и, надеюсь, правильно сформулированный вопрос:

```
Что необходимо для того, чтобы iOS-приложение попало в App Store?
```

Вот начальные условия:

1. Приложение в 85% готовности
2. Аккаунт разработчика есть.

Хотелось бы получить развёрнутый, обстоятельный ответ от людей, которые обладают подобным опытом.

---

Мечта об идеальном результате: чтобы руководствуясь лишь ответами, которые появятся (надеюсь) здесь, можно было увидеть своё приложение на App Store.

Хочу предложить формат, в котором хотелось бы получить ответ:

Первая часть: ссылки на официальные материалы, которыми вы пользовались, и любые полезные смежные с официальными материалы, которые точно не стоит упустить из виду.

Вторая часть:

```
 * с чем пришлось столкнуться лично вам?
 * на что, независимо от специфики приложения, в любом случае необходимо обратить внимание?
 * особый пункт: рекомендации или ограничения по коду, используемому в приложении
```

**Особая просьба** не отвечать однострочными ответами типа "RTF: Apple guides, guidelines, ... - там всё написано" или опять же однострочными и загадочными ответами типа "Нельзя использовать private API" - это точно не увеличит количество информации в данном топике, да и, пожалуй, в космосе вообще.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО ПОЗЖЕ 1**

Ни одного хорошего ответа так и не появляется, печаль. Сам же я не пишу ответ, так как релиз моего приложения затягивается. Обязательно опишу свой опыт, когда увижу берега AppStore.

Comment: непонятно, имеется ли уже аккаунт разработчика?

Comment: Да, конечно! Подправлю вопрос, спасибо.

Comment: Очень странный и неконкретный вопрос. То ли вам нужна пошаговая инструкция, как собирать билд и подписывать. толь как правильно писать описания, толи ещё что.

Comment: Ну и как берега? Обещали написать...

Comment: Да, не написал в свое время ответ. Очень много воды утекло. Может быть еще напишу, или может быть Вы попробуете :) ?

Answer (score -2):

> Мечта об идеальном результате: чтобы,
> руководствуясь лишь ответами, которые
> появятся (надеюсь) здесь, можно было
> увидеть своё приложение на App Store.

Увы, скорее всего это так и останется мечтой - очень сильно зависит от везения, в моей практике было как то что пропускали полную фигню (в т.ч. с крашами и нарушением лицензий источников данных), так и то что апдейт приложения зарубали на вещи, которая в изначальном приложении уже была пропущена.

На практике я бы сказал что требования эппл к приложениям написаны так, что при необходимости можно развернуть почти любое.

Answer (score -5):

Надеюсь эта подборка Вам поможет, сохранял всё для себя.

К сожалению, не могу прикрепить более двух ссылок, репутации не хватает, поэтому выкладываю ссылку на скачивание txt со всеми ссылками.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vstv6oh0m2htwof/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8.txt?dl=0

Чтобы не удалять предыдущее, напишу ниже:
"Что проверяют при публикации в AppStore?"
https://toster.ru/q/205598?utm_source=tm_habrahabr&utm_medium=tm_block&utm_campaign=tm_promo

Comment: Просмотрел 10 ссылок из предоставленных 20 - ни одной ссылки про, собственно, попадание в AppStore.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что меня минусуют из-за этого нарушения - "Не используйте ссылки, кроме как на ресурсы, которые поддерживают то, что вы написали. Ссылки – это не замена информации в самом ответе, и **они должны непосредственно относиться к части вашего ответа**."

Comment: Да,вы всё верно поняли. Не надо постить в ответ десятки ссылок, надо своими словами изложить, что вы из них подчерпнули.